# Bokeh plot wouldn't show title

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization, bokeh

Trying to plot a graph with Bokeh and the title of the graph wouldn't show.

```
import pandas 
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

df=pandas.read_excel("http://pythonhow.com/data/verlegenhuken.xlsx",sheet_name=0)

df["Temperature"]=df["Temperature"]/10
df["Pressure"]=df["Pressure"]/10
 
p=figure(plot_width=500,plot_height=400,tools='pan')

p.title.text="Temperature and Air Pressure"
p.title.text_color="Gray"
p.title.text_font="arial"
p.title.text_font_style="bold"
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None
p.xaxis.axis_label="Temperature (°C)"
p.yaxis.axis_label="Pressure (hPa)"  

p.circle(df["Temperature"],df["Pressure"],size=0.5)
output_file("Weather.html")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `title` parameter in your figure.

For example:

```
p = figure(plot_width=500,plot_height=400,tools='pan', title='MyTitle')
```

Comment: Tried that too and didn't work either. Not sure if it has something to do with the pandas dataframe. I am plotting with dataframes.

Comment: I tried to copy and paste your program on spyder and the title of the graph is shown correctly, without making any changes. What editor do you use for python?

Comment: Jupyter 6.1.4. It had something to do with the jupyter notebook. Reinstalled the bokeh module. It works now after I passed the title parameter as suggested and took out "p.title.text_color="Gray"". Thanks much!

Comment: It's a pleasure, remember to accept the answer.

Comment: Switched over to JupyterLab and the original codes works.